# Differentiate is the string android device id or ios

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

I'm writing a library for pushing notifications which will work for both Android and ios. User will only call the push method and give the deviceId.
Is there a way somehow to know is given id Android or iOS, so I can call specific code for Android or iOS.
I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is the following, when the mobile registers in Apple/Google it gets an ID, then I send a request to a php that inserts that ID and the platform of the mobile in a MySQL database. When I need to send push notifications, I can make a select in that table to get only iOS devices, Android devices or both.

Something like this:

```
insert into devices_table (device_id, device_platform) values ("whateveryourIdIs", "android");
```

Then, to fetch it from the database

```
select * from devices_table where device_platform = "android"
```

So you get all the android devices and can push notifications to them.

Hope that helps, or at least give you some more ideas.

Comment: I dont want to keep the second parameter - device_platform

Comment: Then you can count the characters of the ID. Apple returns a 64 char string and Android a 163 char string, but this is not reliable because it may vary.... In the other hand, all my Android IDs start with "APA91...", but I don't know if they all start that way.